# SDL android NDK managing return button

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl-2

I am using the SDL-2.0.3 along with NDK-r10e, I'm attempting to make the return button switch the app to the background so I tried to use the function SDL_MinimizeWindow() but It does nothing ! is this a bug or do I miss something ?

here is my code :

```
if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_AC_BACK)
    {
            SDL_MinimizeWindow(window);

            SDL_Log("window minimized !\n");
    }
```

everything just work fine and I get the log message when the button is pressed but the window is not minimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't appear to be supported on Android (there's not really anything corresponding to minimizing a "window" on Android, unless you count finishing an `Activity`).

The `SDL_MinimizeWindow` function looks like this:

```
void
SDL_MinimizeWindow(SDL_Window * window)
{
    CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC(window, );

    if (window->flags & SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED) {
        return;
    }

    SDL_UpdateFullscreenMode(window, SDL_FALSE);

    if (_this->MinimizeWindow) {
        _this->MinimizeWindow(_this, window);
    }
}
```

Where `_this`  is an `SDL_VideoDevice *`, which is set to point to an `SDL_VideoDevice` for the appropriate platform at runtime. [The Android video driver](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/android/SDL_androidvideo.c) only sets up the following 3 Window-related functions:

```
device->CreateWindow = Android_CreateWindow;
device->SetWindowTitle = Android_SetWindowTitle;
device->DestroyWindow = Android_DestroyWindow;
```

Trying to perform any other operations on an `SDL_Window` on Android is likely to do nothing.

Some further information in the form of a couple of lines of code from [SDL_androidwindow.c](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/android/SDL_androidwindow.c):

```
window->flags &= ~SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;     /* window is NEVER resizeable */
window->flags |= SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;     /* window is always fullscreen */
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but is there an other way to switch the widow or do I need to call java ?

Comment: thank you that was helpfull, it seems that sdl has some limitations but it still looks cool !